# Getting error for drush site-install :Unable to find a matching SQL Class

Tags: drush, composer

I have created a drupal project using composer:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev ./ --stability dev -vv
```

Then I downloaded drush using this command:

```
composer global require drush/drush
```

Now I try to install the drupal site using this drush command:

```
drush si standard --db-url=mysql://***:***@localhost/recommande_db --site-name=***** --account-name=*** --account-pass=*** --account-mail=*****
```

I'm getting this error:

```
exception 'Drush\Sql\SqlException' with message 'Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your[error]

database connection details.' in

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:588

Stack trace:

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(573):

drush_sql_get_class(Array)

#1

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/site_install.drush.inc(117):

drush_sql_get_class()

#2 [internal function]: drush_core_pre_site_install('standard')

#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(366):

call_user_func_array('drush_core_pre_...', Array)

#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(217):

_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)

#5 [internal function]: drush_command('standard')

#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(185):

call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)

#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67):

drush_dispatch(Array)

#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):

Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()

#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()

#10 {main}
```

I tried all the suggestions found in several forum but no solution.
Can you help please!

For your information here the result of the "drush status" command:

​

```
PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                         

 PHP configuration      :                                                       

 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                               

 Drush script           :  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.recommandemoi.ma/vendo 

                           r/drush/drush/drush.php                              

 Drush version          :  8.1.2                                                

 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                 

 Drush configuration    :                                                       

 Drush alias files      :
```

Comment: Make sure you have php_mysql installed (e.g. `dpkg -l | grep php` on ubuntu)

Comment: both php and mysql are installed. I'm using mac os and the php already installed in the os. I'm also using mysql of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you execute drush from the web folder.

Comment: I would prefer saying "within the **Drupal** folder"

Comment: yes it's the "web" folder in my case since I've created with composer create